# Java download file

Tags: java, http, файлы, download

Добрый день.

Как можно скачать файл по url, получив его параметры в виде имени и расширения?

Все найденные примеры совершают потоковую запись в уже созданный файл с указанным именем и расширением.

Спасибо

Comment: вам нужно распарсить страничку. потом получить названия файлов и потом скачивать. так?

Comment: Нет, пользователь в форме дает линк на файл, мне нужно его получить, распознать формат и сохранить у себя.

Comment: Я вот этим пользуюсь https://hc.apache.org/ для загрузки с http-серверов. Распознать формат помогут заголовки http, если сервер их выдаст вместе с файлом. Иначе сами крутитесь как хотите. Можно поискать как с этим делом управляются разные браузеры. Попадалось однажды описание для chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, понятие расширения пришло из Windows. В Linux название файлов включает и то, что находится после точки тоже. Получить названия файла можно, если сервер его включил в `Content-Disposition`. Ну, по крайней мере, [стандарт HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) говорит, что эта информация находится именно там. `Content-Disposition` можно взять так:

```
String uri = "http://www.website.com/download/file.pdf";
URL url = new URL(uri);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
Map header =conn.getHeaderFields();
header.get("Content-Disposition")
```

Проблема в том, что не все это делают. Например Google Drive на команду download в `Content-Disposition` возвращает json.txt, в котором есть инструкции по файлу. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
disposition: "SCAN_CLEAN"
downloadUrl: "https://doc-10-bc-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx?e=download"
fileName: "Oxford_dictionary.zip"
scanResult: "OK"
sizeBytes: 431943
```

Есть в header ещё `Content-Type`. Из него можно выудить отдельно расширение (точнее медиа-тип) файла. Брать нужно как-то так:

```
String uri = "http://www.website.com/download/file.pdf";
URL url = new URL(uri);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
String type = conn.getContentType();
```

Возвращает он строку типа:

```
application/pdf
```

Но чего-то стандартного, насколько я знаю, нет.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!